# Multicast over SSH

Tags: ssh, tunneling, multicast

1. I have two LANs: 10.x.x.x and 192.x.x.x. On each LAN I have a Linux machine (10.x.x.5 and 192.x.x.5) but they are not routers.
2. I can open ssh from 192.x.x.5 to 10.x.x.5.
3. There are multicast udp channels available for lan 10.x.x.x. Namely, I may listen them from 10.x.x.5.

The question is: May I share these multicast channels for machines from LAN 192.x.x.x?
Any proxy, SSH tunneling, etc?

many thanks,

Answer (score 4):

In order to route multicast traffic, you need a userspace daemon like `smcrouted` (recommended) or `mrouted`.

Since you'll also be needing some kind of interface representing the destination network in the routing table, you could create tunnel interfaces for your SSH connection using the `ssh -w 0:0`. This will create an interface `tun0` on both your SSH hosts.

Answer (score 2):

I was able share the multicast from one network subnet to another using the following [tutorial](http://zarb.org/~gc/html/udp-in-ssh-tunneling.html).